# How to disable Xcode navigator items Glow effect?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

As you can see `ViewController.swift` looks normal. But sometimes, when I select swift files xcode add glow effect.

Do you know how to disable or solve this effect?

[image: normal]
[image: problem]

Comment: i thought xcode was having some issues when it did that. It went back to normal after couple of clicks.

Comment: Yeap :) But, I just want to solve for forever.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow as it is not programming related, rather simply a question about software that happens to be used for programming.